# pyttsx3 выдает ошибку без её описания

Tags: python, python-3.x, tts, pyttsx3

делаю своего голосового помошника. Исходный код вот тут: https://github.com/FallenNephalem/voice_assistant/blob/master/assistant.py
все это выдает мне вот такой трейсбэк:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "assistant.py", line 6, in <module>
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
  File "C:\Users\даня\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\даня\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\даня\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 52, in __init__
    self._driver = self._module.buildDriver(weakref.proxy(self))
  File "C:\Users\даня\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 23, in buildDriver
    return SAPI5Driver(proxy)
  File "C:\Users\даня\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 43, in __init__
    self.setProperty('voice', self.getProperty('voice'))
  File "C:\Users\даня\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 88, in setProperty
    token = self._tokenFromId(value)
  File "C:\Users\даня\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 68, in _tokenFromId
    tokens = self._tts.GetVoices()
  File "C:\Users\6F13~1\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.7\C866CA3A-32F7-11D2-9602-00C04F8EE628x0x5x4.py", line 2957, in GetVoices
    , OptionalAttributes)
  File "C:\Users\даня\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 467, in _ApplyTypes_
    self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(dispid, 0, wFlags, retType, argTypes, *args),
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Ошибка.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147200967), None)
```

как видно, суть ошибки не описана и мне интересно, в чем на заключается и как её решить.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36064723/pywintypes-com-error-2147352567-exception-occurred-0-none-none-none